# How to left align text whilst still being centered?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have a simple p tag with some sample text which is currently centred. However, for the text to all align to one side (like what the arrows show below), i would have to use `text-align: left;`.

Whilst this works, the sample text would no longer in the centre of the webpage.

My current code:

```
.aligned-p-text {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  /*unsure how to carry on from here :/ */
}
```

How could i center the text and align it all with the red line i have shown below? Thanks in advance :D

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `text-align:justify;` like we see in newspapers.

Comment: When a chunk of text breaks across multiple lines, it will also take up the (almost) full width of its container. This means what you're asking is achieved, in practice, by simply using `text-align: left`. If that still doesn't achieve what you want, you'll need to provide more detail on why. For example, by providing sample HTML showing both scenarios and a description of what you feel is wrong with them.

Comment: Yeah dw the associated question answers it